how to create automatic creating of subdomains via nginx and dnsmasq
should i use bash script for creating cname records and make configs of subdomains with link or what should i do? I tried to use some solutions from internet to do it via nginx but it didn't work, i'm using fedora linux, the only thing that get in my head is using
